# How to set UTF8 encoding for Alamofire POST request body?

Tags: ios, encoding, utf-8, alamofire

I want to send UTF8 encoded JSON body to my REST API. My code right now is

```
var body : [String:Any]? = ["version":Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String ?? ""];
.
.
body?["type"] = type
var url : String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"url") as! String
url.append("MobileLogin")
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters:body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseData) in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
    .
    .
    }
}
```

The problem is that the JSON sent in not UTF8 encoded. Any idea of how to set something like "JSONEncoding.encode("UTF8")" in the Alamofire request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
let options = NSJSONWritingOptions()
    let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters!, options: options)

    mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = data
```

or other way

```
extension String: ParameterEncoding {

    public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
        request.httpBody = data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        return request
    }

}

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [:], encoding: "myBody", headers: [:])
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more your solution?